# Postman inconsistent behaviour with cURL request

Tags: postman

I have the following API downloaded in JSON from Swagger Editor:
PUT http://10.37.64.243/m2m/fim/items/fim:device:manager/operations/getAllDeviceTypes?exclude={{exclude}}
with exclude being an environment variable set as : href,metadata,name,arguments

Nominal use requires basic authentication, in this case it works and I get a JSON body with expected result. It properly works in Postman (so I think my import is correct)

If no authentication is provided:

- in Swagger Editor : nominal behaviour, request is rejected with error code 401
- in Postman : UNEXPECTED behaviour, I end up with status code 200 and it returns a response body identical to the one that I get when authenticated
- if I generate the cURL code snippet from Postman and launch it out of Postman: nominal behaviour, I get the same error as the one I get in Swagger Editor (the one expected)

Why do Postman behave differently from the cURL request ??
I probably do something wrong, but I can't figure out what

Thanks for any help

Alexandre

Comment: It is a problem of context as when I sign out then sign in the problem doesn't appear. However if I do a test with authentication I can no longer do the test with No Auth. This is a real issue when playing collections :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found out that the server returns a cookie that holds authentication validation. So after a valid authentication, whatever the request (with or without authentication) it will be considered as authentified.

Unfortunately, the only way to overcome that problem is to remove the cookie by hand through the "Manage cookies" window. Postman does not implement a function that erase it (even through the pm.cookies and pm.cookies.clear() function).

Postman developpers are aware of that, but there's no scheduling for this feature ...

EDIT: the feature is followed here https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/3312